# ssh into Ubuntu through router

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ssh

I set up a Ubuntu server and connect it to my router. I assign a fixed internal IP to it and ssh within the local network is always fine.

However, even if I set port-forwarding to my server, there was no response. `ssh user@externalIP` did not work (no response). I suspect that it was my router which blocks it, so I set external port as 10 and internal port 22. `ssh user@externalIP -p 10` has no response.

My router is a TP-Link C9 archer. The online support told me TP-Link now blocks ssh for my security. Is there any other way to work around?

Simon

Comment: 1. use port in the range of >1024, e.g. port 9898. 2. open port 9898 in your router. 3. [edit] your question with the output of `ssh -vvv user@externalIP -p 9898`

Comment: I would rather use VPN

Comment: Are you trying to connect using the external IP *from within the LAN*? if so the issue may be that your router does not support NAT loopback.

Comment: @steeldriver
I am not connecting the external IP within the LAN. But ssh the internal IP works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of forwarding ports, you might consider using VPN to connect to your Network.
(See [TP-Link FAQ](http://www.tp-link.de/faq-1545.html)).

Once connected, you can connect with your internal IP:

```
ssh user@internalIP
```

As long as the router firmware is up to date and you choose a strong password, this is considerably safer. Attackers will attack the router instead of your computer.

Comment: This is the best solution right now. Thanks RoVo.